# How to set timeout in hessian c sharp

Tags: c#, hessian

I am using [Hessian C#](http://www.hessiancsharp.org/) client in my project to talk to a Hessian Java server.

```
using hessiancsharp.client;

String url = "http://127.0.0.1:2000/test";

CHessianProxyFactory factory = new CHessianProxyFactory();
```

I didn't find a timeout option for the Hessian C# client (unlike the setReadTimeout in the Hessian Java client).

Can anybody help me how can I set time out in Hessian C# client?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a short look into the sources. It seems that specifying timeouts is currently not supported. For a patch, you probably would have to modify the method calls in the class [`CHessianMethodCaller`](http://hessiancsharp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hessiancsharp/HessianCSharp/hessiancsharp/client/CHessianMethodCaller.cs?revision=1.8&view=markup). This class uses the standard .NET [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest_members.aspx) class that exposes a `Timeout` property.

Comment: Hi divo, thanks for the response. I tried to set the timeout in the CHessianMethodCaller but as far I see it didn't seem to be timing out based on my given value.